# Save email attachment to excel file corrupts file

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, mailmessage

I have a `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` which contains attachments, when saving them as files all Excel files are corrupt and I cannot open them after.
It works fine with PDF files.

Does anybody have some code that works with Excel files? both .xlsx and .xlsm

I have tried different version of the code shown, but every time the file is corrupt

```
Dim buffer(convert.ToInt32(attachment.ContentStream.Length)) As Byte
Dim file As FileStream

attachment.ContentStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

file = New FileStream("C:\example.xlsx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)

file.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

file.Dispose()
```

I would like to be able to use the excel files that are send as attachment the same way I can with PDF

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please could you mark up your code in the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the attachments themselves are not corrupt?  Can you open the files successfully from a mail client?

Comment: `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` is the wrong option, you want `FileMode.Create` as otherwise, if there was a previous file with the same name but longer, the end part is not truncated and Excel will consider it to be corrupted.

Comment: E.g. if you have an existing file "example.dat" with a content of "11111" and you use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` to write a new content of "222" to it, you will end up with the content "22211".

Comment: I have also tried using create, and i still get a corrupt file.
The attachment themselves are not corrupt, the email is one I send my self.

Comment: I see you have a good answer already, but for future reference `Dim buffer(convert.ToInt32(attachment.ContentStream.Length)) As Byte` should be `Dim buffer(convert.ToInt32(attachment.ContentStream.Length - 1)) As Byte` otherwise you get an extra byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why that doesn't but I would expect this to work:

```vb
Using fs = File.Create("file path here")
    attachment.ContentStream.CopyTo(fs)
End Using
```